# Why does this AJAX call take so long?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

This takes between 2-4 seconds normally, which seems like far too long for the work it is doing. 
Here is the AJAX:

```
$("#IngTable").html("<center><img src=../img/loading.gif /></center>");

    var search = document.getElementById("IngSearch").value;
    var apiLink = "/API/Ingredient/Search?search=" + search;
    $.ajaxSetup({ accepts: "application/json" });
    $.ajax({
        url: apiLink,
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            var ingredients = JSON.parse(data);
            var htmlIngred = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < ingredients.length; i++) {
                htmlIngred += "<tbody><td><span>" + ingredients[i].Name + "</span></td><td><a class='btn btn-success btn-mini' onclick='addIngred(" + ingredients[i].IngredientId + ");'>Add</a></td></tbody>";
            }
            document.getElementById("IngTable").innerHTML = htmlIngred;
        },
        error: function (a, b, c) { }
    });
```

And here is the Web API Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public string IngredientSearch(string search)
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var db = new Glubee.Model.GlubeeEntities();
        var results = db.Ingredients.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(search)).ToArray();
        sw.Stop();
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results);
    }
```

There is only 16 things in the ingredients table, each being no more than 20 characters long.

Does anyone have any idea where the issue might be in this that makes it take so long?

Edit: Here is my Global.asax.cs page if it is helpful:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

And here is my RouteConfig:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Put a profiler on your database and check your Sql execution

Comment: The IngredientSearch is the one taking too long?

Comment: @benPearce I put a stop watch at the start and end of the IngredientSearch function and it gets between 30-100ms, most of the time close to 40ms, so i do not think the problem lies in that function.

Comment: @rikitikitik please see above comment. thank you for the help.

Comment: @user1308743 the name of the method in web API is IngredientSearch and in ajax you are calling /API/Ingredient/Search?search so is this correct web api call

Comment: @HatSoft It is entering that function since it breaks there if i put a break point... although honestly now that you point that out, i'm not sure how or why it's working. Odd. I tried changing it to just Search, the way I intended the structure to be, and it still works, and still takes just as long unfortunately. Nice catch nonetheless, though!

Comment: Please shows what is inside the HttpRouteMap you will find it in Global.asax.cs

Comment: @HatSoft I added my global.asax.cs and my RouteConfig to the main question for easier reading. Thanks!

Comment: Center tag is deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/center

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you identified exactly what's slow yet ?

For example; in your IngredientSearch  method, if you change the code from

```
[HttpGet]
public string IngredientSearch(string search)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var db = new Glubee.Model.GlubeeEntities();
    var results = db.Ingredients.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(search)).ToArray();
    sw.Stop();
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results);
}
```

to

```
[HttpGet]
public string IngredientSearch(string search)
{
    return String.Empty;
}
```

Does it still take a long time ?

If so; then we've got to look at a script library problem; if not - then it's your DB layer that's at fault.

Bugs like this are often a pain to track down, so you *must* forget assumptions and test things bit by bit.
The above change eliminates a lot of problems, for very little effort gives you a big clue.

PS: Sorry, I know this isn't an answer as such; but I wanted to post it as one so that I could highlight the code change clearly; please don't down-vote!

Comment: I realise that change above may cause problems with your Javascript, but we're only doing this to identify where the problem actually is; the Javascript error caused by this is a red-herring.

Comment: Following your advice I have been able to track down the problem. It's taking a long time both in Serializing to and fron JSON, because unaware to me, it was not just getting and serializing the 'ingredients' i wanted, but everything in each table that related to it, which included pictures. Looking back it makes sense and explains my confusion, i timed how long it took to get the results and it was very quick, but serializing it before it was returned was not included in the stopwatch time.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just rewrote it to make a list of objects that have the Name and Id i need without the rest contained in results, and it feels almost instant. 
Thanks!